# Streaming data over sockets

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, concurrency, monitor

I want to broadcast live data from one server to multiple clients using `Socket`.
However, I'm running into concurrency issues with my current implementation.

```
public class Connection {
    private volatile bool readyToSend;
    private Queue<byte[]> q;
    private object bufferMonitor;

    public Connection { 
        // initialize all things etc and connect
    }

    [...] // some other functions which are irrelevant for this problem

    private void ClientConnected (SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
        // called by Thread A
        [...]
        readyToSend = true;
        WaitingForResponse(args);
    }

    private void WaitingForResponse (SocketAsyncEventArgs) {
        // called by Thread A
        if (q.Count == 0) {
            lock (bufferMonitor) {
                Monitor.Wait(bufferMonitor);
            }
        }
        if (q.Count != 0) {
            byte[] data;
            lock (q) {
                data = q.Dequeue();
            }
            args.SetBuffer(0, data.Length);
            args.ConnectSocket.SendAsync(args);
            // Will send all bytes and recall to WaitingForResponse afterwards
        } else {
            // Will recall this function if nothing happened.
        }
    }

    internal void SendIfConnected (byte[] data) {
        // called by Thread B
        if (readyToSend) {
            lock (q) {
                q.Enqueue(data);
            }
            lock (bufferMonitor) {
                Monitor.PulseAll(bufferMonitor);
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

The problem with this implementation is simply, that the change to `readyToSend` when a client connects is not visible in the second thread - the second problem is, that if you put a breakpoint in the `SendIfConnected` function and change the value manually to true, that the `Monitor.Wait()` will never return although Monitor.PulseAll is executed.

Also, I kind of think that there should exist some easy solution to my original problem and that the whole idea of using a byte[] Queue for a live broadcast isn't the best one. I would appreciate any point into some better direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but feel like there's some information missing here.

1. In the code that's given, bufferMonitor is never initialized.  If it isn't done in some code that you haven't included, then I would be expecting the lock call to fail.
2. You appear to be saying that readyToSend is never set to true.  From the code supplied, this would suggest that the clientConnected method is never being called, or [...] is throwing/returning before that line of the method is executed.  Are you sure clientConnected is being called?
3. Where does 'put a break point there' refers to?
4. As I understand it, the Monitor.Wait (assuming the lock object has been created) is only going to return if the Monitor.PulseAll is executed, after thread A has gone into a wait state.  Are you sure that this is the sequence of events that's happening?  If the pulse happens before wait is called, the thread won't wake up.
5. Stupid question, but are you sure you're calling it on the same instance of the object? So the queue is populated correctly?

Comment: - readyToSend is actually set to true, but thread B doesn't see this / the Monitor.PulseAll is called multiple times, before and after the Monitor.Wait call.

Comment: @Etan: Stupid question, but are you sure you're calling it on the same instance of the object? So the queue is populated correctly?

Comment: Thanks :P That was the problem. Accidently, there were two instances and the client always connected to the one which had the queue which was not populated ^^ If you want you can repost your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Etan: I've updated my answer :)  At least you found the problem.